# Can't generate routes through FOSJsRoutingBundle

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.3

I'm using a AJAX call trough `$.ajax()` in one of my twig templates and because I need to call a URL so I'm using [FOSJsRoutingBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSJsRoutingBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/README.markdown). After read the docs, follow every steps and write this code in my template:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $("a.step").click(function() {
        var id = $(this).attr('id');

        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: Routing.generate('category_subcategories', {parent_id: id}),
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(ev) {
                // here I build the next
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

I got this error in Firebug console:

```
ReferenceError: Routing is not defined
url: Routing.generate('category_subcategories', {parent_id: id}),
```

What could be wrong there?

**UPDATE**

The route at PHP controller is this one:

```
/**
 * Get subcategories based on $parent_id parameter
 *
 * @Route("/category/subcategories/{category_id}", name="category_subcategories", options={"expose"=true})
 * @Method("GET")
 */
```

Now it generate the route but cause this other error:

> "NetworkError: 404 Not Found -
>   http://my.url.domain/app_dev.php/category/subcategories?parent_id=6"

Why?

Comment: Search for `expose` in the documentation

Comment: Change `Routing.generate('category_subcategories', {parent_id: id})` to `Routing.generate('category_subcategories', {category_id: id})`

Comment: @cheesemacfly I've changed as you suggested and still this error: `"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://devserver/app_dev.php/category/subcategories/6"` don't know why the route is not found